# How to show alertdialog when clicking on button in item in list view

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have tried the following code ..

```
            btnRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putLong("index", item.id);


                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Are you sure you ?");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you suer you want to remove this item from the cart?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    Dialog dd= builder.create();
                    dd.show();

                }
            });
```

but I got the following error ..

```
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.gand.metro.uis.SearchActivity$ItemsAdapter$1.onClick(SearchActivity.java:406)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-11 19:18:50.968: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try by changing the getapplicationContext() to [ActivityName].this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialogs can only be created using Activity contexts, so getApplicationContext() will not work. Instead, add the following global variable to your Activity file:

```
Context mContext;
```

And then add the following to your onCreate():

```
mContext = this;
```

Now, change:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of getApplicationContext() and why it didn't work ?

Comment: getApplicationContext() returns the global Context of your entire Application. AlertDialogs can only be created on an Activity context, which will not be returned via getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

You're using getApplicationContext() when you should be using the activity context
use SearchActivity.this instead