# Alert Builder what did I miss

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add Alert Builder Inside a BaseAdapter under button clicked. 
Here is my code

```
 Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                             AlertDialog.Builder dialogBox=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 dialogBox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          String facebookFriendName = friendsName.getText().toString();
                                String FACEBOOKID = FBID;
                               Log.i("AKO SI: ", ""+facebookFriendName + FACEBOOKID);
                       }
                    });
                    dialogBox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                           }
                        });
                    dialogBox.show();
```

Now I am getting an error  on this part **alert_box.show();**

What seems to be the problem?

**EDIT**
based on your suggestion and comments I change my code above
and add a getter and setter on my Activity

```
private Context context;  
/////////
            public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Under my activity class under binding

```
    adapter2 =new LazyAdapterGetFriends(this, songsList);   
             adapter2.getContext();    
             list.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

But I am still getting an error saying:

```
*09-11 13:48:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):    at com.fb.connect.LazyAdapterGetFriends$1.onClick(LazyAdapterGetFriends.java:95)

*pointing at AlertDialog.Builder dialogBox=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: What error you're having? Post your logcat?

Comment: please note alert dialog cant be build in aplication context

Comment: Actually, why you're passing `activity.getApplicationContext()` here. Instead of `activity.getApplicationContext()` you can pass the `Context` which is accessed from `Activity` to `BaseAdapter` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ab.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
           @Override 
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              String facebookFriendName = friendsName.getText().toString();
                    String FACEBOOKID = FBID;
                   Log.i("AKO SI: ", ""+facebookFriendName + FACEBOOKID);
           }
        });
        ab.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               @Override 
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               }
            });
        ab.show();                       
    }                
});
```

hope help

**EDIT**

try [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917003/how-to-show-alertdialog-when-clicking-on-button-in-item-in-list-view/11917023#11917023)

AlertDialogs can only be created using Activity contexts, so getApplicationContext() will not work. Instead, add the following global variable to your Activity file:

```
Context mContext;
```

And then add the following to your onCreate():

```
mContext = this;
```

Now, change:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Comment: I cannot use your code Is giving an error when I try to change MainActivity.this saying Multiple markers at this line
 - No enclosing instance of the type MyFriends is accessible in scope

Comment: if you getting error use only "this" like AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: @DeepakSwami Actually there is a button inside a listview and there is a adapterclass. what I want to do is add a dialog box when the user click's on a button that is inside a listview

Comment: Found it, using your code I stored mContext on my setter context and call it on my builder. Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

**Before show dialog you have to create a Alert Dialog .**

// create alert dialog

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alert_box.create();
```

// show it

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Please check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/) .

Answer (score 0):

May this solves your problem

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the following line

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_box = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

Instead of using `activity.getApplicationContext()` you should be using a locally stored context variable.
getApplicationContext for a **AlertDialog.Builder** fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code, as it requires Activity context rather than Application context

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert_box = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.this);
```